# Process Landsat8 data in AWS S3 from EC2 instance

Tags: landsat-8, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I'm wondering what is the best way of processing huge amounts of Landsat8 images stored in the AWS S3 buckets from an Ec2 instance located in the same availability zone.

Should I download the scenes that I need each time I have to process them and then delete when I'm done, and do the same thing every time I need to do some processing?

Or is there a better way, like mounting the S3 bucket into the EC2 instance? I have seen tools like Fuse for mounting, but I am not sure if this is the best way of processing the data.

Comment: I am also trying to get Landsat 8 images from AWS into ArcGIS. ESRI has provided Landsat 8 image services that can be accessed via an add-in (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f331af8569fb4f19bd74954eddc44bd3) or other options. But, I was wondering if I can use the latest and greatest image services from Amazon Web into ArcGIS.

Comment: Please don't post new questions as answers.